# Facing issue while login in Sandbox trial org

Tags: authentication, salesforce

[image]

When I am trying to login on the sandbox free trial org I am facing this issue .It seems the sandbox has been expired I don't know what to do now I've issued this org on 27th of September 2023 if it is expire please tell me what about my data which i have stored in these trial days .

Anyone Knows what was the issue here ?

Comment: As it's not directly related to programming the question is poor fit for stack overflow. Try asking on dedicated sister site? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/ sounda like job for SF help (raise a case) or contact your SF account manager...

Comment: Please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746). This is off-topic here.